# Views pager not printing

Tags: 7, views, paging

I am working on a project in Drupal 7 and the pager is not working properly. It will display on the block but not on the page no matter what I do. I have even tried changing the pager_id and that yields no results what so ever. We are using Template files but it works on other pages just not this one. I have checked the settings and all seem identical.

I have googled until I am blue in the face and nothing I do seems to make it work. If someone could help it would be great this is driving me nuts!

Here are the settings I have
Block
[image]

Page
[image]

```
   <?php
  global $base_url;

  $view = views_get_view('mylab');
  $view->set_display('page_1');
  $view->execute();
  $mylabs = $view->result;
?>
<div id="wrapper" class="page">
<header id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-logo">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
            <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Climate Advocacy Lab'); ?>" />
              </a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-navigation">
        <div class="top-bar">
        <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
          <?php print render($page['main_nav']); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="mobile-header">
  <div class="mobile-logo">
    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home">
      <img src="<?php echo $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'ClimateLab') . '/images/logo-mini.png' ; ?>" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <?php if (!$logged_in): ?>
      <h5 class="guest-message">Become a member?</h5>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="user-controls">
      <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="user-menu">
      <a class="menu-open" href="#">
        <img src="<?php echo $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'ClimateLab') . '/images/menu-icon.png' ; ?>" />
      </a>
      <a class="menu-close" href="#">
        <img src="<?php echo $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'ClimateLab ') . '/images/menu-icon-close.png' ; ?>" />
      </a>
      <?php print render($page['main_nav']); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<main id="main" role="main" accesskey="s">
  <div class="system-message">
    <?php print $messages; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="before-content container">
    <?php if ($page['highlighted']):
      print render($page['highlighted']);
    endif; ?>

    <?php if ($tabs): ?>
      <div class="tabs-wr">
        <?php print render($tabs); ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
    <?php if ($action_links): ?>
      <ul class="action-links">
        <?php print render($action_links); ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <div class="above-body">
      <h2>Your favorite resources from the Lab all in one place.</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="resources-panel">
      <div class="resources-result">
         <p style="max-width:650px;">Select the "+MyLab" button next to items in the Resource Library and State-level Data tools for quick and easy access to your favorite resources, all in one place.</p>  
        <?php
          foreach ($mylabs as $item):
            $resource = node_load($item->nid);
        ?>
          <?php print _view_resource_node($resource); ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
      </div>
      <?php  if ($pager) {  print $pager;   }else{ echo("NO PAGER");} ?>
        
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that it's not being hidden? Strip all CSS with a browser extension/tool, can you see the pager?

Comment: CSS wasn't hiding it, I disabled all css and there was no button for loading for content at all. I have also done the header output as recommended on other sites and it is seeing the right number of records 5 of 24

Comment: Check if a **views-view--page.tpl.php** file exists, that file should have `<?php

if ($pager) {
  ?>
    <?php

  print $pager;
  ?>
  <?php

}
?>`

Comment: I put in an else to put out a string and there doesn't seem to be a pager. So now I am really lost

Comment: [This is how it's suppose to be](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views/-/raw/7.x-3.x/theme/views-view.tpl.php)

Comment: I added my code to the post. @NoSssweat that was helpful however that doesn't even produce a pager for me.

Comment: Did you flush the cache? Another place you could look to see is inside of template.php, and see if there is a preprocess function that's unsetting the pager

Comment: Browser cache yes, is there a drupal cache?

Comment: Yes there is, you need to clear all caches at this URL `/admin/config/development/performance`

Comment: Nope that didn't do a thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116035/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-the-gugaru).